# How to represent a taproot output with more than 2 scriptleaves as a descriptor?

Tags: taproot, output-script-descriptors

I read in the Bitcoin Core doc an example of a taproot output descriptor with 2 script paths :

```
tr(c6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5,{pk(fff97bd5755eeea420453a14355235d382f6472f8568a18b2f057a1460297556),pk(e493dbf1c10d80f3581e4904930b1404cc6c13900ee0758474fa94abe8c4cd13)})
```

I tried to pass a descriptor with a third script path, but I'm met with an error `tr(): expected ')' after script expression`

That makes sense since I read in the same doc that the syntax for taproot descriptor is `tr(KEY,TREE)`, and that `TREE` is defined as:

```
* any SCRIPT expression
* An open brace {, a TREE expression, a comma ,, a TREE expression, and a closing brace }
```

This is consistent with what I saw in the rust-bitcoin library, where a `TAPTREE` is either a leaf, or 2 trees.

My question is what if I wanted to commit a third script, a very simple one like the 2 in the example?

I think I could compute the root of my tree myself and use the `rawtr()` descriptor with the output pubkey, but what if I want to prove there's no hidden commitment?

I guess I could give all the scripts and that one could figure it out by recreating the scriptpubkey and check it's the same, but that's cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a Merkle tree with script paths `S1` and `S2` on the second level of the Merkle tree and script path `S3` on the first level of the Merkle tree the descriptor notation is:

`tr(KEY,{{S1,S2},S3})`

where `KEY` can be any key expression including public key, x-only public key, WIF private key, xpub, xprv or xpub/xprv with derivation path.

Pull request [#22051](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22051) added support for `tr(KEY,{{S1,{{S2,S3},...}},...})` descriptors and the notation was confirmed in pull request [#21365](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21365#issuecomment-793300643).

Comment: Thanks, how didn't I think of it *facepalm*  

Maybe we should update the descriptor documentation with an example